# How to fix table with angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datatables

I am using the DataTables Jquery https://datatables.net/ , but  i am filling in the table with AngularJS, but when i use any of properties of Data Table the results disappear, i think that is  because is running the page and then running the code js , how is correct way for filling the table with AngularJS?

```
<table
                        class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable order-column"
                        id="sample_1">
                        <!--sample_1  -->
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>E-mail</th>
                                <th>Ações</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <tr class="odd gradeX"
                                ng-repeat="obterUsers in ObterUsuarios | orderBy:'username'">
                                <td>{{obterUsers.id }}</td>
                                <td class="center">{{ obterUsers.username}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <button class="btn btn-xs green dropdown-toggle" type="button"
                                            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                            Ações <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                            <li><a href="#!/UsuarioAlteracao/{{obterUsers.id}}">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Editar
                                            </a></li>
                                            <li><a ng-click="deleteUsuario(obterUsers)" href="">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Excluir
                                            </a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Some pictures about program:

[image]

[image]

Comment: there is an angular module for datatables:  http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/welcome

Comment: as a general guide, use a directive to wrap jquery components where u can handle binding, events etc. or just use an angular component if u have one that does what you want

Comment: where is your DataTable  javascript code?